# VBA, Merge Tables in sheets based on identifier column in specified sheet

Tags: vba, excel, replace

I am new to VBA. I have two sheets containing two Tables sheet 1 is a glossary of abbreviations in a column under header "Material" and the descriptions in a column under header "Material Description". Sheet 2 is a data set containing a column under header "Customer Names", a column under header "Material", and a column under header "Invoiced Values".

Example:

```
Sheet 1      
Material    Material Description
   X               Hot
   B               Cold
   C               Temp
-------------------------------------
Sheet 2       
Material       Invoice Value
   X               2.7645  
   X               3.9
   B               4.6
```

Desired output:

```
Sheet 3
Material        Invoice Value
   Hot               2.7645  
   Hot               3.9
  Cold               4.6
```

I am trying to:

1. Find columns with specified headers in respective sheets
2. For each row column "Material" of sheet 1, find the "Material" in  sheet 2 that corresponds to same "Material" in sheet 1
3. Replace the text in the row of column "Material" in sheet 2, with the corresponding value of "Material Description" in sheet 1

For item 1 I have gotten as far as :

```
Sub Replace()

    Dim startrow As Long
    Dim custrng As Range
    Dim matdatrng As Range
    Dim valrng As Range
    Dim dscrng As Range
    Dim matname As Range

    startrow = 2

    Set rcustrng = Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Find("Customer Name", , xlValues, xlWhole)
    Set matdatrng = Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Find("Material", xlValues, xlWhole)
    Set valrng = Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Find("Invoiced Value", xlValues, xlWhole)
    Set matname = Worksheets("Names").UsedRange.Find("Material", xlValues, xlWhole)
    Set dscrng = Worksheets("Names").UsedRange.Find("Material Description", xlValues, xlWhole)

End Sub
```

Any and all help/suggestions is appreciated, I am hoping to expand this to three data sets.

Comment: so you want to loop thru materials in sheet2 and if there is a match paste the material description under material in sheet2?

Comment: your code does not do much, it just finds the range of the headers, which is not crucial, do you have many rows like 10k or sth? You need to simplify the question and step by step, this is not a difficult code, but since you have asked for 1-2-3 etc members did not get involved with much of work that you are demanding

Comment: @Ibo thanks for the feedback, I edited and added a simple example which should clarify the code's use and output, I have 10k+ columns and over 30 rows, but as the code is to be generalized to sheets with columns containing those headers, I need to do it in VBA

Comment: @Ibo sorry, 30 columns and 10k+ rows

Comment: @EI_1988 you have many rows so it is better to use arrays and dictionaries to make it a lot faster. I assume all of your headers in all of the sheets are in ROW 1 and all of these specific columns are column 1,2,3 or they are in different columns that should be found first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do by using the code in the following link contributed by Mumps:

https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/138286-vba-to-join-tables-with-unique-key-in-first-column

```
Sub CopyRange()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets("OCData").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows,      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Dim ID As Range
Dim foundID As Range
For Each ID In Sheets("OCData").Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
    Set foundID = Sheets("NamesList").Range("B:B").Find(ID, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not foundID Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("NamesList").Range("B" & foundID.Row & ":E" & foundID.Row).Copy Sheets("OCData").Range("J" & ID.Row)
    End If
Next ID
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Awesome code, saved me loads of time.